# Reverse of a Integer with integer overflow condition

Tags: c, math

```
long long  reverse(long long x) {
    long long reversednum=0;
    int sign=1;
    if(x<0)
        sign=-1;
    x=abs(x);

    while(x)
    {
        reversednum=reversednum*10;
        reversednum=reversednum+(x%10);
        x=x/10;
    }

    return (reversednum<INT_MAX || reversednum>INT_MIN)?reversednum*sign:0;
}
```

Most of my test cases got satisfied except for this 1534236469 which returns the output 1056389759. I have seen many suggestions and changed it to long long. But still produces the same result. Hope some would help me out. Thanks in advance!! **The input is assumed to be a 32-bit signed integer. My function should return 0 when the reversed integer overflows**

Comment: overflow of signed integers is undefined; you have to check for the overflow *before*  doing the operation.  `INT_MAX` and `long long` are from different integer domains too.

Comment: @ensc: very probably OP's `long long` are wider than `int`s and don't overflow with his values.

Comment: even if i use LLONG_MAX and LLONG_MIN it shows the same result.

Comment: `return (reversednum<INT_MAX || reversednum>INT_MIN)?reversednum*sign:0;`  should be `return (reversednum<INT_MAX && reversednum>INT_MIN)?reversednum*sign:0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you must be using %ld inside printf...Use %lld! Simple mistake :)

Analysis of what was happening:

When you entered 
1534236469
result should be 9646324351 which was correctly produced by the function(yes it was!).

In binary,  9646324351 is written as 00000010 00111110 11110111 00111010 01111111 . Now your compiler allocates 4 bytes for long and 8 bytes for long long. So when you print long (where it should have been long long) the compiler will simply take the first 4 bytes from the binary and discard the rest. This means that your compiler simply takes 00111110 11110111 00111010 01111111 which is equivalent to 1056389759 in decimal. Hence the output... So it means that your function and logic is correct(phewwww....!!!!) but you made a silly mistake.

Comment: Not, it wasn't, `9,646,324,351`, which is the correct result (not the one you put in your answer, that misses the previous to last digit `5`) is **FAR OVER THE 32bit LIMIT FOR A 32BIT NUMBER, even unsigned** which is 4,294,967,296.  You have to rethink you answer before posting!!!  Your problem doesn't resolve doing binary arithmetic, as you are converting base 10 numbers.... and multiplication by 10 can lead a number to overflow well below the `MAX_INT` or `MAX_UINT` limit.

Comment: @Luis Colorado Dude...I wrote that 964632431 myself...didn't copy from the terminal. So might be a typo. And I am 100% sure that my answer is correct. Let go off your ego. Even the op has marked it as right. If there is a logical error or you have a better solution. Please enlighten us.

Comment: Yes, it  is not a matter of ego.  The number you have written doesn't fail at all, is the one that the PO wrote which fails.  And it fails by the reasons exposed in my answer, not because my ego.  You are the only who has mention another's ego, and believe me, your answer is incorrect.  For a number to fail in 32bit integer you need at least ten digits, and the number you wrote has only nine.  You have edited your response (i see) so try the number again, and see it failing, despite of the format you use to print it.

Comment: Dude.. Sorry for the ego part, if offensive, but it was just a typo that I missed 5. 0kay do one thing. The output that op provides.. Convert it into binary. And convert (your output) the correct output to binary. Match the first 4 bytes. You shall see why I am right and why it forced me to say that the op mistakenly has used %d or %ld instead of %lld. Long long generally has 8 bytes length. Long and int generally have 4. So if output long long into long or int... Only first 4 bytes will be regarded. Thats the basic concept of compiler architecture. The way it works!

Comment: @Luis Colorado if you are still not satisfied, just let me know. I have more such examples(even more complicated) that will prove my point. And moreover if a person has been programming for quite a time, trust me, this logic is not even logic. Its equivalent to 2+2=4. Its just the way how it works. And  really sorry for the ego part, no offence btw.

Comment: Well, for a person that has been programming for quite a time, nothing to say, just read my answer (thing that you have not done) and see why a number like `1,000,000,009`, on transforming to `9,000,000,001` can (and does) overflow (even for `unsigned`) To me, this thread is over.  Just keep reading my answer... (and your response continues to be incorrect)  Even your example (leading to a five byte number), with 34 significative bits, overflows a 32 quantity.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite complicated to check the number before you reverse it, so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

long  long reverse(long  long x)
{
  long  long reversednum = 0;

  // just in case
  // please be aware that the minimum size for "int" is 16-bit!
  // you might think about changing it to an actual number if you
  // really need 32-bit
  long  long int_max = INT_MAX;
  long  long int_min = INT_MIN;

  int sign = 1;

  // abs() would have been wrong for "long long", it should have been "llabs()"
  // also: you already checked if x is negative, no need for "abs()" here
  if (x < 0){
    sign = -1;
    x = -x;
  }

  while (x) {
    reversednum = reversednum * 10;
    reversednum = reversednum + (x % 10);
    x = x / 10;
  }

  // you want "reversednum" to be in the range {int_min < reversednum < int_max}
  // hence the need to check both limits
  return (reversednum < int_max
          && reversednum > int_min) ? reversednum * sign : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  long  long x;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s integer\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  errno = 0;
  x = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  if ((errno == ERANGE && (x == LLONG_MAX || x == LLONG_MIN))
      || (errno != 0 && x == 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input %s caused an error in converting: %s\n", argv[1],
            strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("IN  : %lld\n", x);
  x = reverse(x);
  printf("OUT : %lld\n", x);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

As said in the comments but worth to repeat here, too: the limits `int_*` have a guaranteed minimum of only 16-bits (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 5.2.4.2.1)!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that you are assuming that the problem is in the sign bit (and that you cannot overflow with the significant bits), and it isn't there, you get errors well before approaching the sign bit.  After analysing your code, there is a final unsigned 32 bit integer overflow in the last multiplication by 10 (you multiply by 10, not by 2, so you can get up to four new bits in each multiplication, making it easier for an overflow), even if you do `unsigned` arithmetic (which is recommended so you don't need to play with the signs)

Just modifiying a little your code to use `unsigned` arithmetic, and issuing some traces in the `reverse` function to this version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned  reverse(unsigned x, unsigned base)
{
    unsigned reversednum=0;

    while(x) {
        unsigned digit = x % base;
        reversednum *= base;
        reversednum += digit;
        x /= base;
        printf("reverse: digit=%u, reversednum=%u, x=%u, base=%u\n",
                digit, reversednum, x, base);
    }

    return reversednum;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    while ( fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) ) {
        unsigned x = (unsigned) atol(buffer);
        printf("reverse(%u) => %u\n", x, reverse(x, 10));
    } /* while */
} /* main */
```

Execution with your input gives:

```
$ reversed
23
reverse: digit=3, reversednum=3, x=2, base=10
reverse: digit=2, reversednum=32, x=0, base=10
reverse(23) => 32
1534236469
reverse: digit=9, reversednum=9, x=153423646, base=10
reverse: digit=6, reversednum=96, x=15342364, base=10
reverse: digit=4, reversednum=964, x=1534236, base=10
reverse: digit=6, reversednum=9646, x=153423, base=10
reverse: digit=3, reversednum=96463, x=15342, base=10
reverse: digit=2, reversednum=964632, x=1534, base=10
reverse: digit=4, reversednum=9646324, x=153, base=10
reverse: digit=3, reversednum=96463243, x=15, base=10
reverse: digit=5, reversednum=964632435, x=1, base=10  <-- after multipliying 
                                                       by base, unsigned 
                                                       overflows here to 
                                                        9,646,324,350 - 
                                                      2*4,294,967,296 == 
                                                        1,056,389,758
reverse: digit=1, reversednum=1056389759, x=0, base=10
reverse(1534236469) => 1056389759
```

The main problem with your code is that the last digit in your number (a ten digit number) can be `0..9` and **the first digit in your ten digit number cannot be more than `4`** (if it is `4`, then the second cannot be more than `2`... or an overflow ocurs, giving a number that is larger than the maximum possible value for an unsigned)  For example, all numbers greater than 1,000,000,000 finished in 5 or more, will overflow, from the set of numbers that finish in 4, all the ones that finish in 2 or more will overflow, from the numbers that finish in 24, the ones that
finish in `924` that have a previous digit greater than `4`, all will overflow, ... and so until forming the number `MAX_UINT` in the base you are doing the calculations.

This happens also for signed numbers, so you have to limit the domain of your function to not overflow.  As all ten digit numbers with a last digit of `5` will overflow, i'd suggest a maximum value of `1,000,000,005`, for the first number that overflows.  For different bases, you'll have different limits, so you must be careful (I shouldn't allow numbers that greater or equal `base^(floor(log(MAX_UINT)/log(base))) ==> 1,000,000,000`, as you'll begin to get windows of numbers that overflow, interspersed with numbers that don't --- in the case of 32bit unsigned the first number that fails is `1,000,000,005`, while for signed numbers it is `1,000,000,003`)

For 64 bit `unsigned`s, the limit should be at `1.0E19` ( `== 10^((int)(log((double)MAX_ULONG_LONG)/log(10.0)))`), as `10,000,000,000,000,000,002` is the first failing number.  For `signed`s, the limit should be at `1.0E18`, as `1,000,000,000,000,000,039`should be the first number to fail.

## JUST TO COMPLETE

to consider a function that works properly with a set of 32bit integers, you should make an assertion like the one you do, but instead of using `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`, you have to use actual bounding limits for your number.  Something like

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
int32_t reverse(int32_t x)
{
    assert(x > -1000000000 && x < 1000000000);
    int32_t reversednum = 0;
    while(x) {
        int digit = x % 10;
        reversednum *= 10;
        reversednum += digit;
        x /= 10;
    } /* while */
    return reversednum;
} /* reverse */
```

would allow to even disable the range check at runtime for production code. `base` has been fixed to `10`, as this was your function, and the `assert(3)` limits depend of the election of the numbering base.

Answer (score -1):

You're using INT_MAX and INT_MIN, when you should probably be using LLONG_MAX and LLONG_MIN

```
long long  reverse(long long x) {
long long reversednum = 0;
int sign = 1;
if (x<0)
    sign = -1;
x = abs(x);

while (x)
{
    reversednum = reversednum * 10;
    reversednum = reversednum + (x % 10);
    x = x / 10;
}

return (reversednum<LLONG_MAX || reversednum>LLONG_MIN) ? reversednum*sign : 
0;
}

int main(){
    long long int i;
    scanf_s("%lld", &i);
    printf("%lld",reverse(i));
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
}
```

It has been tested on the values 1232 and your given value that shows bad results(1534236469).

Comment: but my code too works well on 1232 and other small values but it does not satisfy the input 1534236469

Comment: @AnandhKishan, you have to approach the limit (in base 10, just 1% nearer to the `LLONG_MAX` limit to get into trouble.  See my answer.